# jQuery cookies (HTML)

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, navbar

I have a Modal that will open whenever the pages load. I want that when I click on a button on the modal, it will change the background color of my navbar. But I want to do that with cookies, so that the background color should stay.

Modal:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fg").click(function() {
        $("#nav").css({
          $.cookie('background', 'gray');
          
          });
        
       
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Choose Design</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
  <div id="fg"><span class="label label-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Dark</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
  <div id="fg2"><span class="label label-info" data-dismiss="modal">Light</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
  <div id="fg3"><span class="label label-default" data-dismiss="modal">Gray</span></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the jQuery code doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the `background-color` propperly.

*Code*

```
//on page load read cookie, if value exists set color
var color = $.cookie('background');
if (color) {
    //set color
    $("#nav").css({
        "background-color": color
    });
}
//Bind click handlers
$("#fg").click(function() {
    //Get color text
    var bgColor = $(this).find('span').text().trim();
    //Set cookie value
    $.cookie('background', bgColor)
        //set color
    $("#nav").css({
        "background-color": bgColor
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But now,  how can i set the modal that it only pop ups when these button were never clicked? With cookies.

Comment: @Hemran, I have already added `//on page load read cookie, if value exists set color
var color = $.cookie('background');
if (color) {
    //set color
    $("#nav").css({
        "background-color": color
    });
}`

Comment: Oh didnt realize it.  Thank you very much :D

Comment: How can i add gradients? Each browser has a different gradient code. how can i all add them in one cookie?

Comment: @Hemran, Create CSS class and use them

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the cookie actually, not reading.

To read the cookie use:

```
var background = $.cookie('background');
```

I'd add `data-background`, and `class="bg-change"` to the div, so that you don't have to repat `.click()` for every single color.
:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div data-background="#000" class="bg-change"><span class="label label-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Dark</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div data-background="#fff" class="bg-change"><span class="label label-info" data-dismiss="modal">Light</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div data-background="#ccc" class="bg-change"><span class="label label-default" data-dismiss="modal">Gray</span></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Script (single click event for all colors):

```
$(".bg-change").click(function() {
    var col = $(this).data('background');
    $.cookie('background', col , { expires: 365, path: '/' }); 
    $("#nav").css({
       'background' : col   
    });  
});
```

---

Consider using [`localStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) instead of `cookie` if server side processing is not required.